# Cancelling power terms in numerator and denominator

Tags: simplifying-expressions

.Dear Community. I have the following expression in Mathematica:

```
(1 + x) (x + (w/(A (1 - y)))^(1/y)) (A (1 - y))^(1/y)
```

I would like to simplify it so that terms like `(A (1 - y))` does not appear anywhere in the denominator, and is multiplied instead. For example, to get:

```
(1 + x) (x*(A (1 - y))^(1/y) + (w)^(1/y))
```

I tried various simplify commands but to no avail. Is there a way to "teach" Mathematica to automatically cancel such terms, and put everything in a "multiplied" form, without having to work with each term sort of "manually"? It is assumed that A>0, and 0

Comment: PowerExpand can do this, but use it cautiously, because it doesn't care that e.g. Sqrt[x^2] != x. Simplify/FullSimplify with assumptions try to be rigorously correct, but they're a bit more tedious to use.

Comment: Your `f` and the desired form are not equal when `y -> 2, A -> 1, w -> 7`.

Comment: I will be setting f = 0, so I need to multiply both sides by (A (1 - y))^(1/y).

Comment: `Simplify[f, y < 1 && A > 0]`? (Provided the assumptions are valid.)

Comment: Thank you, but it does not always work, I guess depends on the problem. let me reformulate my question in a sec.